# Why does OS X delete files directly without moving them into the trash?

Tags: file, trash, macos

On an external HD, when I delete a file, OS X prompts me that the file will be deleted without putting it into the trash folder.
What is the reasons for that?
How can I move it in trash folder before permanently delete it?

Comment: What type of external drive and how is it formatted, what filesystem is it using? How are you deleting the files, via Finder or Terminal? Is the external drive directly physically attached or is it a NAS?

Comment: The issue is symptomatic of a missing .Trashes folder on the external hard drive.

Comment: @user3439894 Is an volume mounted internally to MacPro. Is formatted Apple_HFS. I delete files via Finder.

Comment: @fd0 .Trashes exists

Comment: You first stated "_On an external HD ..._" and now you're saying "_Is an volume mounted internally to MacPro_", which are two different things!

Comment: @user3439894 Yes it's true! That volumes was first mounted in external case. After it was moved internally. I'm sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS X finder maintains a few hidden directories to handle Mac specific filesystem functions like:

- Spotlight = `/Volumes/X/.Spotlight-V100`
- file version history = `/Volumes/X/.DocumentRevisions-V100`
- trash = `/Volumes/X/.Trashes`
- Time Machine (and other) filesystem changes = `/Volumes/X/.fseventsd`

These are suppressed on many network and "foreign" filesystems by design and/or if the filesystem is read-only. You can use the command line tool (or the get information menu command in Disk Utility) to inspect the format of your volume:

```
diskutil list /Volumes/X/
```

Hopefully this is the cause - if your volume is of type Apple_HFS or similar and you don't see the hidden directories, you might need to dig deeper and repair that filesystem or look at some other cause. The simple reason would be that the hidden directories are suppressed by design in your case.

Comment: I had checked all folders and all of them exist. The volume is Apple _HFS . I can't repair permission on that volume. I simply checked _Ignore ownership on this volume_ and everything seem fixed!